# MVC dropdownlist : Setting the value and text based upon table in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a table in database

[image]

I've been able to show the list of TypeName in my dropdownlist in my View

Currently i'm doing this is my controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult CreateModule()
        {
            var moduleTypes = _db.ModuleTypes.Select(moduleType => moduleType.TypeName).ToList();
            var model = new CreateModule
                {
                    TypeNames = moduleTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = m,
                            Text = m,
                        })
                };
            return View(model);

        }
```

and in view

```
 <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedModuleTypeName, Model.TypeNames)</div>
```

That results to something like this
[image]

based upon my code, I'll get the `TypeName` from the view in my controller's post method.
How I can I change my code in order to access `Id` of the `TypeName` in controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your Action:

```
public ActionResult CreateModule()
        {
            var moduleTypes = _db.ModuleTypes.Select(moduleType => new { TypeName = moduleType.TypeName, Id = moduleType.Id }).ToList();
            var model = new CreateModule
                {
                    TypeNames = moduleTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                            Text = m.TypeName,
                        })
                };
            return View(model);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select` multiple items instead of single

```
var moduleTypes = _db.ModuleTypes
                      .Select(
                          moduleType => new {
                              Id = moduleType.Id
                              TypeName = moduleType.TypeName}
                      ).ToList();

var model = new CreateModule
            {
                TypeNames = moduleTypes.Select(m => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                        Text = m.TypeName,
                    })
            };
```

The first statement is creating anonymous object using `linq`, and second statement is using it to create `CreateModule`